# SQL statement with JOIN and WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL and trying to solve this problem with two tables Employee and Department. I want display the names of all the employees of 'HR' and 'Sales' departments. 
Tables  are **Employee (emp_id, emp_name, dept_id)** and **Department (dept_id, dept_name)**.

Thanks!

Comment: Next time you should show some effort of your own. There must have been some ideas you had yourself which didn't work for some reason. Or haven't you even tried *anything*?

Comment: Like I wrote I tried these problems before asking here. I will keep your instructions in mind from the next time. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select e.emp_name from 
Employee e inner join Department d
on e.dept_id = d.dept_id
Where d.dept_name in ('HR','Sales');
```

This query will compare the `dept_id` of `Employee` table and `Department` table. Those values matched will be returned. then out of all the fields you will select the `emp_name` and limit the employees belonging to `HR` and `Sales` department using the `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks bro! that worked I was actually confused with the 'where' clause in this problem. Thanks

Comment: You are most welcome:) Do upvote and accept the answer if useful :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again,  actually I am trying to explore the questions with different scnerios but with the same tables and came across with  some different kind of problem.
How can I display all the department names which has more than 10 employess. 
Thanks!

Comment: try this: Select d.dept_name from 
Employee e inner join Department d
on e.dept_id = d.dept_id group by d.dept_name having count(*) > 20

Comment: @user2439492: This is a completely different question. Try to solve it yourself first. If it doesn't work, ask a new question showing what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: I tried both the problems before  but could not solve then I came here. My mistake that I didn't ask this problem in a new question.

Answer (score 2):

As you only want to display employee data, only select from that table. The rest is criteria. You want their department to be either 'HR' or 'Sales', so the straight-forward way of writing this is the IN clause (you could also use the EXISTS clause):

```
select emp_name
from employee
where dept_id in 
(
  select dept_id 
  from department
  where dept_name in ('HR', 'Sales')
);
```

I think this is more easy to read than to join the tables first, only to use one as a filter for the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Employee.emp_name [Emplyee Name] from Employee inner join Department on Department.dept_id=Emplyee.emp_id where Department.dept_name='HR'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get like this,

```
SELECT [emp_name] FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS E
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Department] AS D
ON D.dept_id=E.dept_id
WHERE D.dept_name='HR' OR D.dept_name='Sales'
```